# \cancel draws under thing being canceled

Tags: color, cancel

I'm trying to use `\cancel` from the `cancel` package to strike out some colored text but it is apparent that the diagonal line is drawn first so it doesn't do a very good job of canceling.
[image]

Minimal example.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor,cancel}
\begin{document}
\leavevmode
\cancel{\textcolor{red}{T}}
\textcolor{red}{T}\llap{\cancel{\phantom{T}}}
\end{document}
```

I can obviously use the `\llap`, but that is suboptimal. Is there a better way?

Comment: Probably the best answer is going to be 'take the code and alter it to reverse the order'!

Comment: or use TikZ instead!

Comment: @Joseph: You're probably right about that. Maybe I'll take a look when I get some spare time.

Comment: I think your solution with `\llap` is the easiest way so far. I had a look at the docs, a hack is not easy. Suggestion cancel the word "suboptimal" in you question:) Certainly TikZ is not the answer for this.

Comment: @Yiannis: That's herasy!  TikZ is the answer to _everything_.  Indeed, when computed according to the Magrathean system, the numerical value of TikZ is 42.

Answer (score 12):

Using Tikz :

```
\newcommand{\cancel}[1]{%
    \tikz[baseline=(tocancel.base)]{
        \node[inner sep=0pt,outer sep=0pt] (tocancel) {#1};
        \draw[red] (tocancel.south west) -- (tocancel.north east);
    }%
}%

This is a \cancel{test}
```

Another possibility with Tikz is to use the `strike out` shape:

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.misc}


\begin{document}
Strike \tikz[baseline] \node [strike out,draw=red,anchor=text] {me}; out!
\end{document}
```

Using `pstricks`, in the `pstricks-add` package :

```
%in preamble
\usepackage{pstricks,pstricks-add}

%in document
%example taken from pstricks-add documentation
\psCancel[linecolor=red]{Tikz :-)}
```

Edit 1 : I just realized that the `\psCancel` macro draws the mark before the text to cancel, same as for the `cancel` package. If you want the mark above the text, I guess you should use Tikz.

Edit 2 : Incorporated suggestions about baseline into the Tikz code

Comment: You should add the `baseline=(tocancel.base)` option to `\tikz` to make sure that the baseline doesn't change. Try a `\cancel{Ag}` or `\cancel{test\strut}` to see the difference. Also you need `%` after the first `{` and the closing `}` of `\tikz` to avoid spurious spaces.