# Diagonal strikeout starting too low and ending too high

Tags: tikz-pgf, equations, strikeout

I want to strikeout an equation with diagonal line but I've not managed to get the diagonal line to draw as I want. The closest I've gotten is via the first example in [Frédéric's answer of \cancel draws under thing being canceled](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/15916/cancel-draws-under-thing-being-canceled/15958#15958):

```
\documentclass{minimal}

\usepackage{tikz}

\newcommand{\hcancel}[1]{%
    \tikz[baseline=(tocancel.base)]{
        \node[inner sep=0pt,outer sep=0pt] (tocancel) {#1};
        \draw[red] (tocancel.south west) -- (tocancel.north east);
    }%
}%

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}\label{eq:2}
\hcancel{$h_1 \land h_2 \land h_3 \land h_4 \land h_5 \land h_6 \land h_7 \land h_8 \land h_9 \land h_{10}$}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

This produces:

[image: Line starts too low and ends too high]

But the line starts too low and ends too high. The following is what I want:

[image: The line as I want it to draw]

I'd be happy for an option to make the line start slightly earlier and end slightly later too.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can modify Frédéric's code so that `\hcancel` receives four more mandatory arguments controlling the vertical and horizontal shifting for the starting and ending points:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\newcommand{\hcancel}[5]{%
    \tikz[baseline=(tocancel.base)]{
        \node[inner sep=0pt,outer sep=0pt] (tocancel) {#1};
        \draw[red] ($(tocancel.south west)+(#2,#3)$) -- ($(tocancel.north east)+(#4,#5)$);
    }%
}%

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}\label{eq:1}
\hcancel{$h_1 \land h_2 \land h_3 \land h_4 \land h_5 \land h_6 \land h_7 \land h_8 \land h_9 \land h_{10}$}{0pt}{0pt}{0pt}{0pt}
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}\label{eq:2}
\hcancel{$h_1 \land h_2 \land h_3 \land h_4 \land h_5 \land h_6 \land h_7 \land h_8 \land h_9 \land h_{10}$}{-3pt}{3pt}{3pt}{-2pt}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

The new syntax:

```
\hcancel{<text>}{<start. point horiz. shifting>}{<start. point vertical shifting>}{<end. point horiz. shifting>}{<end. point vertical shifting>}
```

[image]

EDIT: using the `xparse` package, the definition of the new command is much more flexible; using something like

```
\usepackage{xparse}
\DeclareDocumentCommand{\hcancel}{mO{0pt}O{0pt}O{0pt}O{0pt}}{%
    \tikz[baseline=(tocancel.base)]{
        \node[inner sep=0pt,outer sep=0pt] (tocancel) {#1};
        \draw[red] ($(tocancel.south west)+(#2,#3)$) -- ($(tocancel.north east)+(#4,#5)$);
    }%
}%
```

allows the use of `\hcancel{<text>}` for the standard behaviour of the command as defined by Frédéric and to use the four (now optional) arguments to control the horizontal/vertical shifting:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\DeclareDocumentCommand{\hcancel}{mO{0pt}O{0pt}O{0pt}O{0pt}}{%
    \tikz[baseline=(tocancel.base)]{
        \node[inner sep=0pt,outer sep=0pt] (tocancel) {#1};
        \draw[red] ($(tocancel.south west)+(#2,#3)$) -- ($(tocancel.north east)+(#4,#5)$);
    }%
}%

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}\label{eq:1}
\hcancel{$h_1 \land h_2 \land h_3 \land h_4 \land h_5 \land h_6 \land h_7 \land h_8 \land h_9 \land h_{10}$}
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}\label{eq:2}
\hcancel{$h_1 \land h_2 \land h_3 \land h_4 \land h_5 \land h_6 \land h_7 \land h_8 \land h_9 \land h_{10}$}[-3pt][3pt][3pt][-2pt]
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 9):

You can create nodes at the beginning and the end of the line, and shift them vertically:

```
\tikzstyle{nosep}=[inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt]
\newcommand{\hcancel}[1]{%
    \tikz[baseline=(tocancel.base)]{
        \node[nosep] (tocancel) {#1};
        \node[nosep, yshift=.5ex]  (from) at (tocancel.south west) {};
        \node[nosep, yshift=-.5ex] (to)   at (tocancel.north east) {};
        \draw[red] (from) -- (to);
    }%
}%
```

You can find the best shifts by trial and error. I chose `.5ex` and `-.5ex` arbitrarily.

Comment: @N.N. And to make the line slightly longer, add `xshift=-1ex` to the `from` node (`+1ex` for the `to` node).

Answer (score 6):

Another possibility is to create a style.

```
\documentclass[]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}  


\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[cancel/.style={path picture={ \draw[#1]
($ (path picture bounding box.south west)+(-3pt,6pt)$) -- ($(path picture bounding box.north east)+(3pt,-6pt)$);
}}]  
\node   [inner sep=3pt,cancel=red] {$2x+3=y$};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: It's possible to place  the code in a macro with arguments.

Comment: When I try to compile this I get: ! Package pgfkeys Error: I do not know the key '/tikz/path picture' and I am going to ignore it. Perhaps you misspelled it.

Comment: @N.N. I use pgf 2.1. and perhaps  'path picture' is  defined since the 2.1 but I don't know :( I use this option in several examples and in some answers without problem.

Comment: OK, you're probably right. I've got pgf 2.0 from TeX Live 2009 on my system.

Answer (score 4):

This is thought as enhancement of [Gonzalo’s answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/20648/9237). The more arguments a command gets, the easier one can lose track of them. Here comes the key-value approach to aid.

Therefore I want to show a definition using the package `keycommand`. It could also be done with `xparse` and `l3keys`, but I am used to `keycommand`; in my eyes it is also more suited for end users, at least for cases like this. Note, though, that there is a bug in, and you must include the patch provided by Joseph Wright in [his answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/35794/9237) to the question [How do I use \ifcommandkey , or how do I check if a key was given?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/35733/how-do-i-use-ifcommandkey-or-how-do-i-check-if-a-key-was-given) after the package was loaded *(actually you would need this only in cases, when you use the command `\ifcommandkey`)*.

Note, that I additionally added a key to change the line color, used in third example.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{keycommand}
% Patch by Joseph Wright ("bug in the definition of \ifcommandkey (2010/04/27 v3.1415)"),
% https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/35794
\begingroup
  \makeatletter
  \catcode`\/=8 %
  \@firstofone
    {
      \endgroup
      \renewcommand{\ifcommandkey}[1]{%
        \csname @\expandafter \expandafter \expandafter
        \expandafter \expandafter \expandafter \expandafter
        \kcmd@nbk \commandkey {#1}//{first}{second}//oftwo\endcsname
      }
    }
%--------%
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\newkeycommand{\hcancel}[hshiftstart=0pt,vshiftstart=0pt,hshiftend=0pt,vshiftend=0pt,color=red][1]{%
  \tikz[baseline=(tocancel.base)]{
        \node[inner sep=0pt,outer sep=0pt] (tocancel) {#1};
        \draw[\commandkey{color}] ($(tocancel.south west)+(\commandkey{hshiftstart},\commandkey{vshiftstart})$) --
                                  ($(tocancel.north east)+(\commandkey{hshiftend},\commandkey{vshiftend})$);
  }%
}%

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}\label{eq:1}
\hcancel{$h_1 \land h_2 \land h_3 \land h_4 \land h_5 \land h_6 \land h_7 \land h_8 \land h_9 \land h_{10}$}
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}\label{eq:2}
\hcancel[hshiftstart=-3pt,vshiftstart=0.5em,hshiftend=3pt,vshiftend=-0.5em]
{$h_1 \land h_2 \land h_3 \land h_4 \land h_5 \land h_6 \land h_7 \land h_8 \land h_9 \land h_{10}$}
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}\label{eq:3}
\hcancel[hshiftstart=-3pt,vshiftstart=1em,hshiftend=3pt,vshiftend=-1em,color=blue]
{$h_1 \land h_2 \land h_3 \land h_4 \land h_5 \land h_6 \land h_7 \land h_8 \land h_9 \land h_{10}$}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image: example output]

Answer (score 1):

I use PSTricks in this answer. Please adjust the parameters until they suit your preference best. The parameters given in the code below are self-explanatory.

[image]

```
\documentclass{minimal}

\usepackage{pstricks-add}
\psset{linecolor=red}
\def\myeq{\psDefBoxNodes{A}{h_1 \land h_2 \land h_3 \land h_4 \land h_5 \land h_6 \land h_7 \land h_8 \land h_9 \land h_{10}}}
\begin{document}

\centering

Your settings:
\begin{equation}
\myeq
\ncline[nodesep=3pt,offsetA=-1pt,offsetB=3pt]{A:bl}{A:tr}
\end{equation}
\\[5mm]

Controlling the length:
\begin{equation}
\myeq
\ncline[nodesep=10pt,offsetA=-1pt,offsetB=3pt]{A:bl}{A:tr}
\end{equation}
\\[5mm]

Controlling the left node:
\begin{equation}
\myeq
\ncline[nodesep=3pt,offsetA=-1pt,offsetB=-10pt]{A:bl}{A:tr}
\end{equation}
\\[5mm]


Controlling the right node:
\begin{equation}
\myeq
\ncline[nodesep=3pt,offsetA=10pt,offsetB=3pt]{A:bl}{A:tr}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Just as remark: See [Why should the minimal class be avoided?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/42114).

Answer (score 1):

Coming late to the game.

Here is a `picture` based solution, which compiles of course faster as it does not need load all the tikz libraries. With the help of the `pict2e` package.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pict2e}
\usepackage{color}

\makeatletter
% in our modern era, you should redefine this using xparse facilities
% so that you can add all parameters you wish more easily
% for example the linethickness which I hardcode here.
% Also, the \@firstoffour etc... is just because LaTeX's \newcommand
% admits only defining 1 optional parameter. With xparse, you can
% provide possibly more convenient user interface.
\newcommand\@firstoffour[4]{#1}
\newcommand\@secondoffour[4]{#2}
\newcommand\@thirdoffour[4]{#3}
\newcommand\@fourthoffour[4]{#4}

\newcommand\MyCancel[2][{0pt}{0pt}{0pt}{0pt}]{%
  \begingroup
    \sbox0{#2}%
    \edef\MyCancel@xoffsetleft {\number\dimexpr\@firstoffour#1}%
    \edef\MyCancel@yoffsetleft {\number\dimexpr\@secondoffour#1}%
    \edef\MyCancel@xoffsetright{\number\dimexpr\@thirdoffour#1}%
    \edef\MyCancel@yoffsetright{\number\dimexpr\@fourthoffour#1}%
    \edef\MyCancel@width {\number\wd0}%
    \edef\MyCancel@height{\number\ht0}%
    \setlength{\unitlength}{1sp}%
    \begin{picture}(\MyCancel@width,\MyCancel@height)
      \linethickness{1pt}% this may be made another parameter
      \put(0,0){\box0}
      \color{red}%         also this one
      \Line(\MyCancel@xoffsetleft,\MyCancel@yoffsetleft)% \Line does not like space here!
           (\numexpr\MyCancel@xoffsetright+\MyCancel@width\relax,
            \numexpr\MyCancel@yoffsetright+\MyCancel@height\relax)
    \end{picture}%
  \endgroup
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
\MyCancel[{-1pt}{+1pt}{+0.5pt}{-1.5pt}]{$\displaystyle h_1 \land h_2 \land h_3 \land h_4 \land h_5 \land h_6 \land h_7 \land h_8 \land h_9 \land h_{10}$}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I should have used `\providecommand` for the `\@firstoffour` etc... in case some package define them. Hopefully with same definition..