# Any way to change color of \not

Tags: color, amsmath, math-operators

I often use command `\not` just to cancel off symbols in my equations and i would need an advice on how to change the color of this command.

Comment: Have a look at the [`cancel`](http://texdoc.net/pkg/cancel) package manual and the disclaimer in the end.

Comment: Related Question: [Diagonal strikeout starting too low and ending too high](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/20643/diagonal-strikeout-starting-too-low-and-ending-too-high).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some similar command for obtaining colored \cancelto (some math package is probably missing)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{cancel}
\newcommand\crossout[3][black]{\renewcommand\CancelColor{\color{#1}}\cancelto{#2}{#3}}
\begin{document}
  $\crossout[red]{\infty}{a^2} +   \crossout[blue]{0}{b^2}  =   \crossout[green]{\infty}{c^2} $
\end{document}
```

[image: result]

Answer (score 5):

As mentioned by percusse in the comments, it is better to use `cancel` package since `\not` can not strike out more than one variable (say `(x+y)`). You can define a macro to change the color of strike line as your need:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[thicklines]{cancel}
% \renewcommand*{\CancelColor}{\color{red}}%%if only one color is enough
\newcommand*{\mynot}[1]{\renewcommand{\CancelColor}{\color{#1}}\cancel}
\begin{document}
  \[
    \mynot{red}{\in}
  \]
  \[
    (\mynot{green}{x+y})(x-y)
  \]
  \[
    \mynot{black}{x+y}
  \]
  \mynot{blue}{This}  is  cancelled  out. % \cancel works in text mode also.
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: The OP does not seem to ask about canceling complete expressions but about negating single relation symbols. For this purpose `\not` is quite sufficient. Furthermore the author of »[cancel](http://ctan.org/pkg/cancel)« explicitly discourages users from using the package (at the very end of its manual).

Answer (score 4):

A very simple method would be to temporarily change the text color and then switch back to black. This can be done by a new command.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\newcommand*{\cnot}[1][black]{\color{#1}\not\color{black}}

\begin{document}
  \[
    \cnot[red]\in
  \]
\end{document}
```

The new command takes an arbitrary color as optional argument.

Comment: `\newcommand*{\cnot}[1][black]{\mathrel{\color{#1}\not}}` would avoid restating the current color.

Comment: Even more, the "current color" might not be black.

Comment: do you need `fontenc` as part of the MWE?

Comment: @egreg: Hm, I always forget things like `\mathrel`.

Comment: @lockstep: The probability that the current color is not black is vanishingly low.

Comment: @cmhughes: Not really. But it can't do any harm.

Comment: @ThorstenDonig A casual user might think that `T1` and `fontenc` are essential for the solution.

Comment: egreg has made my point- I always try and make my MWE as minimal as possible and load only the packages that are required.