# How can I fill a table cell with a dash in tabular?

Tags: tables

I have a basic table in the `tabular` environment, and I want to fill a cell with a dash, to show that there is nothing to go in that cell. I've tried just using dash, but can't get one that's long enough or connected.

Comment: `\hrulefill` perhaps or that may be a bit low or you can use `\rule` to make any rule of any fixed length and height above the baseline

Comment: perhaps the [cancel package](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/cancel) can be of use here (or perhaps http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/20643?)

Comment: `\hrulefill` does what I want it to, but it also messes up my cell colouring, where I've used `\rowcolor`

Comment: I'd simply use `--` or `---`

Comment: @egreg I've tried those, they're too narrow for my liking

Comment: It's what's commonly used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here I define a `\longdash` command, by default it's (slightly less) than an em-dash; it has an optional argument: `\longdash[4]` is (slightly less than) four en-dashes.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs,xcolor,colortbl}
\usepackage{xparse}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\longdash}{ O{2} }
 {
  --\prg_replicate:nn { #1 - 1 } { \negthinspace -- }
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff


\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{ccc}
\toprule
Foo & Bar column & Baz column \\
\midrule
123 & 456 & 789 \\
\rowcolor{red!20}%
\longdash & 42 & \longdash[2] \\
\rowcolor{green!20}%
\longdash & \longdash[3] & \longdash[4] \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Filling with `\rowcolor` involved seems tricky and, in my opinion, not desirable. However, I would recommend simply using an em-dash for this.

[image]