# Active ! Character Hangs within TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf, catcodes, strikeout, cancel

The MWE below

- makes the `!` active in math mode using the solution from [Make Characters Active via Macro in Math Mode](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/299805/4301) and
- uses the `tikz` `\hcancel` via [Diagonal strikeout starting too low and ending too high](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/20648/4301).

However, when the `!` is active *within* the `\hcancel` compilation seems to hang?

---

The desired output is:

[image]

but if I uncomment the code intend to produce the the last canceled term the compilation seems to hang.

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{xcolor,etoolbox}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}


\makeatletter
%% https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/299798/make-characters-active-via-macro-in-math-mode
\newcommand{\DeclareMathActive}[2]{%
  % #1 is the character, #2 is the definition
  \expandafter\edef\csname keep@#1@code\endcsname{\mathchar\the\mathcode`#1 }
  \begingroup\lccode`~=`#1\relax
  \lowercase{\endgroup\def~}{#2}%
  \AtBeginDocument{\mathcode`#1="8000 }%
}

\newcommand{\std}[1]{\csname keep@#1@code\endcsname}
\patchcmd{\newmcodes@}{\mathcode`\-\relax}{\std@minuscode\relax}{}{\ddt}
\AtBeginDocument{\edef\std@minuscode{\the\mathcode`-}}
\makeatother

\DeclareMathActive{!}{\mathclose{\textcolor{blue}{\std{!}}}}



%% https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/20643/diagonal-strikeout-starting-too-low-and-ending-too-high
\newcommand{\hcancel}[5]{%
    \tikz[baseline=(tocancel.base)]{
        \node[inner sep=0pt,outer sep=0pt] (tocancel) {#1};
        \draw[red] ($(tocancel.south west)+(#2,#3)$) -- ($(tocancel.north east)+(#4,#5)$);
    }%
}%

\begin{document}

Active ! works: $3!$

Cancel with non-active ! works: 
\hcancel{$3\std{!}$}{-3pt}{0pt}{3pt}{0pt}

\medskip
Combine cancel with active ! hangs: 
%\hcancel{$3!$}{-3pt}{0pt}{3pt}{0pt}% <-- This hangs!!

\end{document}
```

Comment: As part of its workarounds connected to `babel`, TikZ changes the meaning of the active `!` to `\tikz@nonactiveexlmark`, which expands to a `!` with category code 12, which then expands to `\tikz@nonactiveexlmark`, which…

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're being very unlucky.

The French module for `babel` makes `!` into an active character, in order to implement the French conventions about punctuation. Therefore, since the beginning, TikZ takes precautions against this, because it uses `!` in its syntax. Therefore it assigns a new meaning to the active `!` in case French is being used.

It essentially does

```
\begingroup\lccode`~=`! \lowercase{\endgroup\def~}{\tikz@nonactiveexlmark}
\edef\tikz@nonactiveexlmark{\string!}
```

Similarly for `;`, `:` and `|`. So in a `tikzpicture` environment the assigned meaning `\mathclose{\textcolor{blue}{\std{!}}}` is lost. Worse, when `!` is math active, TeX enters an infinite loop:

- `!` in math mode is treated *as if* it were active, so it is replaced by its meaning `\tikz@nonactiveexlmark`
- `\tikz@nonactiveexlmark` is replaced by its meaning, a `!` with category code 12
- `!` in math mode is treated *as if* it were active, so it is replaced by its meaning `\tikz@nonactiveexlmark`
- …

Since you're not using French, you can redefine `\tikz@nonactiveexlmark` do to the same as the math active `!`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{xcolor,etoolbox}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\makeatletter
%% http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/299798/make-characters-active-via-macro-in-math-mode
\newcommand{\DeclareMathActive}[2]{%
  % #1 is the character, #2 is the definition
  \expandafter\edef\csname keep@#1@code\endcsname{\mathchar\the\mathcode`#1 }
  \begingroup\lccode`~=`#1\relax
  \lowercase{\endgroup\def~}{#2}%
  \AtBeginDocument{\mathcode`#1="8000 }%
}

\def\tikz@nonactiveexlmark{\mathclose{\textcolor{blue}{\std{!}}}}

\newcommand{\std}[1]{\csname keep@#1@code\endcsname}
\patchcmd{\newmcodes@}{\mathcode`\-\relax}{\std@minuscode\relax}{}{\ddt}
\AtBeginDocument{\edef\std@minuscode{\the\mathcode`-}}
\makeatother

\DeclareMathActive{!}{\mathclose{\textcolor{blue}{\std{!}}}}



%% http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/20643/diagonal-strikeout-starting-too-low-and-ending-too-high
\newcommand{\hcancel}[5]{%
    \tikz[baseline=(tocancel.base)]{
        \node[inner sep=0pt,outer sep=0pt] (tocancel) {#1};
        \draw[red] ($(tocancel.south west)+(#2,#3)$) -- ($(tocancel.north east)+(#4,#5)$);
    }%
}%

\begin{document}

Active ! works: $3!$

Cancel with non-active ! works: 
\hcancel{$3\std{!}$}{-3pt}{0pt}{3pt}{0pt}

\medskip
Combine cancel with active ! hangs: 
\hcancel{$3!$}{-3pt}{0pt}{3pt}{0pt}% <-- This hangs!!

\end{document}
```

The text now tells a lie. `;-)`

[image]

Comment: Wow, those darn French go and make things complicated! :-)  I would have thought since these are active only in math mode, that I would not run into such problems - oh, well.  So, what would I need to do for the other characters, especially the `:` and`|`.  Don't think I'll have an issue with the `;`.

Comment: @PeterGrill The same as for `!`, I'd say.