# Conflict between cancel and align

Tags: amsmath, incompatibility, cancel

It seems that the `cancel` package does not behave well as one needs to cross out 'large' amount of text as the bar crosses the next line, and the result clearly seems unacceptable.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{cancel}
\usepackage{amsmath}


\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
&\cancel{1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1=0}\\
&1+1=2
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

It there a way to remedy this?

Comment: Does `\bcancel` instead of `\cancel` help?

Comment: @Christian Hupfer. Thank you for your quick feedback. The problem is the same, provided the formula on the next line is long enough. Also, it does not behave well with fractions, as it adds extra vertical space (I had the impression that the slope of cancel could be automatically adapted to stay within the boundaries of a normal vertical space).

Comment: A better approach could be using `tikz`

Comment: I have just found that my question is a duplicate thanks of your tikz suggestion. https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/20643/diagonal-strikeout-starting-too-low-and-ending-too-high Thank you very much.

Comment: That linked solution  is basically the same what I tried a few moments ago. Happy TeXing

Comment: @ChristianHupfer I have added at https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/394341/4686 a picture based solution with offset possibilities for start and end of line. For drawing lines, no need for full-fledged tikz.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

<strike>Often, people ask for "no-package" solutions. Here it is.</strike> Well I do use package `pict2e`...  and package `color`. Really need to take my memory medication now.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\usepackage{pict2e}
\usepackage{color}

\newcommand\MyCancel[1]{%
  \begingroup
    \sbox0{#1}%
    \setlength{\unitlength}{1sp}%
    \begin{picture}(\number\wd0,\number\ht0)
      \linethickness{1.5pt}
      \put(0,0){\copy0}
      \color{red}
      \Line(0,0)(\number\wd0,\number\ht0)
    \end{picture}%
  \endgroup
}

\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
&\MyCancel{$\displaystyle1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1=0$}
\\
&1+1=2
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

You can customize the command to get the line to possibly start and end at some offset.

Comment: some `\m@th` should be used to cancel `\mathsurround` setting. Telling that in case anyone uses this. Good enough for default as it is.

Comment: For a more complete `\MyCancel` with optional offsets, see https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/394341/4686.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. While this question already add a solution, I am sure this is very valuable to have alternative ones such as yours.