# \cancel or \bcancel draws non-parallel lines in math mode; looking for better solutions

Tags: math-mode, cancel

I have very similar lines in math mode under a `\align` environment. When I use `\cancel` or `\bcancel` it doesn't draw parallel lines for what should be similar width terms.

I think a simple repro would be:

```
\begin{align}
    f &= \left(\cancel{\frac{\partial v}{\partial x}}\right) \\
    g &= \left(\cancel{\frac{\partial v}{\partial z}}\right)
\end{align}
```

[image: cancel non-parallel]

I tried to cook up some tikz based solutions off of [this issue](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/20643/diagonal-strikeout-starting-too-low-and-ending-too-high?rq=1), but the dont work well with say `\left(\frac{\partial u}{\partial y} + \cancel{\frac{\partial v}{\partial z}}\right)` and produce something like [image: tikz math]

edit:

Comment: I guess the documentation of the cancel package recommends against using it in math mode, but I can't find a simpler alternative.

Comment: The `x` is minimally wider than `z`, enough to trigger the different slope. You could try with something like `\cancel{\mkern1mu\frac{\partial v}{\partial z}\mkern1mu}` but it's surely not elegant...

Comment: Thanks! That certainly works, even though it might not be the most elegant solution for a general case, it's a quick fix. I'm happy to just create a custom cancel command with this for now

Comment: Since the slant of the cancellation on the fraction with the "z" is a bit more attractive (in my eyes), you might adapt @campa's suggestion to instead use `\mkern(-1mu)` on the fraction with the "x".

Comment: Bad luck to land right at a transition between slopes. Adding (or subtracting) a small width to both fractions will give equal slope selection. In the red-slash example, the color changing has lost the math context (unnecessarily). Put \displaystyle right before \frac.

Comment: Ah the math context makes sense, adding `\displaystyle`  fixes the problem in the second example, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `\cancel` macro uses internally picture mode, and measures the width and height of its argument to decide the slope of the stroke. The code

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\setbox0=\hbox{$x$}\showthe\wd0
\setbox0=\hbox{$z$}\showthe\wd0
\end{document}
```

returns

```
> 5.71527pt.
l.3 \setbox0=\hbox{$x$}\showthe\wd0
> 5.0903pt.
l.4 \setbox0=\hbox{$z$}\showthe\wd0
```

so the `x` is minimally wider than the `z`; minimally, and yet enough to trigger the different slope. The quickest (and lest elegant) solution is to add some manual kerning around the symbols.

I implement here this "solution" by the following work-around: the original definition of `\cancel` in `cancel.sty` is

```
\DeclareRobustCommand\cancel[1]{\ifmmode
  \mathpalette{\@cancel{\@can@slash{}}}{#1}\else 
  \@cancel{\@can@slash{}}\hbox{#1}\fi}
```

I patch this (hoping Donald won't mind) by adding an optional argument which adds some kerning to the argument of `\cancel` and subtracts it outside of the cancelled expression, such that the total width remains unchanged.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{cancel}

\makeatletter
\DeclareRobustCommand\cancel[2][0]{%
  \ifmmode
    \mkern-#1mu
    \mathpalette{\@cancel{\@can@slash{}}}{\mkern#1mu #2 \mkern#1mu}%
    \mkern-#1mu
  \else
    \dimen@=\dimexpr 1em*#1/18\relax
    \kern-\dimen@
    \@cancel{\@can@slash{}}\hbox{\kern\dimen@ #2\kern\dimen@}%
    \kern-\dimen@
  \fi}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\[
\cancel{\frac{\partial v}{\partial x}}
\quad
\cancel[1]{\frac{\partial v}{\partial z}}
\quad
\cancel[-1]{\frac{\partial v}{\partial x}}
\quad
\cancel{\frac{\partial v}{\partial z}}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Whether you want to add some width to the fraction containing `z` or subtract it from the fraction containing `x`, as Barbara Beeton suggested in [her comment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/571374/cancel-or-bcancel-draws-non-parallel-lines-in-math-mode-looking-for-better-so?noredirect=1#comment1440021_571374)), is a matter of taste. (I agree with Barbara, but *de gustibus*...)

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to investigate this in detail and for providing a generalizable solution.