# Uniformly oriented cancelling lines across math or texts

Tags: cancel, strikeout

How do I cross out maths to show they vanish with evenly oriented diagonal lines (i.e., all lines parallel?)

I don't like how the crossing lines appear due to size of the expressions. It doesn't matter if the expressions are wide or narrow especially in fractions. Is there a way to modify the diagonal lines? Or is there a better package or option?

Here is my MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[makeroom]{cancel}

\begin{document}

\[
    \frac{1}{1} + \cancel{\frac{1}{2}} + \cancel{\frac{1}{3}} + \cancel{\frac{1}{4}} + \cancel{\frac{1}{5}} + \cancel{\dots} + \cancel{\frac{1}{n-1}} + \cancel{\frac{1}{n}}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image: Output]

Comment: you could make them all the same slope but what slope do you want, all near-vertical like the first 4, so just going through the centre of the fraction?

Comment: but this seems to be a duplicate of the question in the related list in the sidebar: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/571374/cancel-or-bcancel-draws-non-parallel-lines-in-math-mode-looking-for-better-so?rq=1

Comment: Yeah if possible. The link you gave is partially helpful but didn't solve my problem.

Comment: could you expand on the differences, it seemed to be the same question?

Comment: Lines don't align when I use the solution code from the link you provided with my given example. I am not sure what modifications do I need to make here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This uses `\cancelbox` to store a predesigned common cancel slash.  `\mycancel` centers the slash over the contents.  It uses `\mathsavebox` from [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/348566/how-to-create-special-math-macros-which-preserve-the-current-style).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{mathstyle}
\usepackage[makeroom]{cancel}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\mathsavebox}[2]{%
  \setbox#1=\hbox{$\m@th\currentmathstyle#2$}%
}
\makeatother

\newsavebox{\cancelbox}
\savebox{\cancelbox}{$\cancel{\phantom{\dfrac{1}{1}}}$}

\newcommand{\mycancel}[1]{\mathsavebox{1}{#1}{\usebox1\hspace{-\wd1}\makebox[\wd1]{\usebox\cancelbox}}}

\begin{document}

\[
    \frac{1}{1} + \mycancel{\frac{1}{2}} + \mycancel{\frac{1}{3}} + \mycancel{\frac{1}{4}}
    + \mycancel{\frac{1}{5}} + \mycancel{\dots} + \mycancel{\frac{1}{n-1}} + \mycancel{\frac{1}{n}}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image: demo]

Comment: I had to waste my time using tikz nodes to position maths and cross them out diagonally with their own anchors. Yet they were poorly spaced.