# Having all links underlined with dotted line

Tags: cross-referencing, pdf, links, text-decorations

so I'm trying to figure out how to have all links underlined with a dotted line. The furthest I got with [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/26071/how-can-i-have-colored-and-underlined-links-with-hyperref) and [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/27258/how-do-i-write-underline-text-but-with-a-dotted-line) is:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor,soul,lipsum}
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage{tikz}
 \def\@pdfborder{0 0 1}% Overrides border definition set with colorlinks=true
  \def\@pdfborderstyle{/S/U/W 0}
\newcommand{\udot}[1]{%
\tikz[baseline=(todotted.base)]{
\node[inner sep=-1pt,outer sep=0pt] (todotted) {#1};
\draw[dotted] (todotted.south west) -- (todotted.south east); }%}%
\newcommand{\myhy}[2]{\udot{\hyperref[#1]{\color{black}\setulcolor{white}\ul{#2}}}}
\begin{document}
\section{To See}\label{tosee}
\vskip2cm
This is \myhy{tosee}{just to see} what it looks like\footnote{\lipsum[1]}. \lipsum[1-2]
\end{document}
```

The problem is I want to have formatted in this way every singe link in a document (including links to footnotes, webpages, etc.). Any ideas?

Answer (score 6):

What you should do is override the `\ref`, `\hyperref`, `\footnote` commands, and any other command that you use to link. The following code should give you a starting point:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage{tikz}

\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\makeatletter
\newlength\link@width
\newsavebox\link@box

\newcommand{\formatlink}[1]{%
   % --- save the box to be displayed (so that e.g. footnote counters do not
   %     get incremented twice)
   \savebox{\link@box}{#1}%
   % --- calculate the width of the box for later use
   \settowidth\link@width{\usebox{\link@box}}%
   % --- draw the link
   \tikz[baseline=(todotted.base)]{
   \node[inner sep=-1pt,outer sep=0pt] (todotted) {\usebox{\link@box}};
   \draw[dotted, thick] 
      ($(todotted.base)-(.5\link@width,2pt)$) -- +(\link@width,0); 
   }%
}

\makeatother

\AtBeginDocument{%
   % --- replace \ref command
   \let\oldref=\ref
   \renewcommand\ref[1]{\formatlink{\oldref{#1}}}
   % --- replace hyperref command
   \let\oldhyperref=\hyperref
   \renewcommand\hyperref[2][]{\formatlink{\oldhyperref[#1]{#2}}}
   % --- replace footnote command
   \let\oldfootnote=\footnote
   \renewcommand\footnote[1]{\formatlink{\footnotemark}\footnotetext{#1}}
   % --- replace cite command
   \let\oldcite=\cite
   \renewcommand\cite[1]{\formatlink{\oldcite{#1}}}
   % --- introduce secref command   
   \newcommand\secref[1]{\hyperref[#1]{Section \oldref{#1}}}
}

\begin{document}

\section{To See}\label{tosee}
This is Section \ref{tosee}; or refer to it like \secref{tosee}.
This is \hyperref[tosee]{just to see} what it looks like\footnote{\lipsum[1]}. \lipsum[1-2]
How about this?\footnote{And a second footnote}
\end{document}
```

The code introduces a new command, `\formatlink`, which, as the name suggests, formats a link. Its only argument is the text that is to be underlined with dots. The code for `\formatlink` is about the same as what you wrote in your question, with minor changes for better appearance.

Next, the code inside `\AtBeginDocument` (which gets executed at the `\begin{document}` command) overrides the `\ref`, `\hyperref`, and `footnote` commands. It also adds a new command called `\secref`, which could be used to refer to sections in such a way that the word "Section" also gets underlined.

For illustration purposes, I have changed the code of `\formatlink` code slightly, so that every link shows up as a red box; the result is:

[image]

There are probably more commands to override, but it may help you on your way.