# URL with dotted/customized underline AND line breaking

Tags: tikz-pgf, hyperref, urls, ulem

How can I get a **dotted URL underline** with **line breaking**?

I found this solution: [Having all links underlined with dotted line](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/49862/having-all-links-underlined-with-dotted-line) but this TIKZ one does **not work with line breaking**.

I also tried a simpler solution. This results in a dotted line, but also **no line breaking.**

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}  
\usepackage{ulem}
\makeatother
\AtBeginDocument{
   \let\oldurl=\url
   \renewcommand\url[1]{\dotuline{\oldurl{#1}}}
}
\begin{document}
Desired dotted line, but no linebreaking:\\
\url{http://www.very.very.very,very.very.very.very.very.very.very.long.url.com/a/b/c/d/e/df/sadasd/asdasda}
\par Line breaking but no dotted line\\
\oldurl{http://www.very.very.very,very.very.very.very.very.very.very.long.url.com/a/b/c/d/e/df/sadasd/asdasda}
\end{document}
```

This outputs this:

[image]

How to get linebreaking working in combination with dotted (or more in general: customized) underline?

Comment: You can use Martin's code here http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/24279/2388 and then `\tikzul[dashed]{\url{http://www.very.very.very,very.very.very.very.very.very.very.long.url.com/a/b/c/d/e/df/sadasd/asdasda}}`. (If your url contains special chars, you will have to store the url first with `\urldef`). You must compile twice.

Comment: This solution of Ulrike does not work: this: "\tikzul[dashed]{\url{A}}" results in "! Undefined control sequence. l.135 \tikzul[dashed]{\url" however without URL it is working (so "\tikzul[dashed]{A}" does work but off course no URL).

Comment: Well you naturally should load the url or hyperref package if you want to use the command `\url`.

Comment: Thanks Ulrike that did the trick. Is this TIKZUL already packaged up?

Comment: Repeated question: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/236337/underline-long-url-and-linebreak/236351

Answer (score 1):

With the commands `\href` and `\allowbreak` I was able to get the desired output. Dotted line and line break. Unfortunately I have no idea how it would be possible to add the `\allowbreak`s automatically after every /.

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref} 
\usepackage{ulem}
\makeatother
\AtBeginDocument{
   \let\oldurl=\url
   \renewcommand\url[1]{\dotuline{\oldurl{#1}}}
}
\begin{document}
Desired dotted line, but no linebreaking:\\
\url{http://www.very.very.very,very.very.very.very.very.very.very.long.url.com/a/b/c/d/e/df/sadasd/asdasda}
\par Line breaking but no dotted line\\
\oldurl{http://www.very.very.very,very.very.very.very.very.very.very.long.url.com/a/b/c/d/e/df/sadasd/asdasda}\\
\href{http://www.very.very.very,very.very.very.very.very.very.very.long.url.com/a/b/c/d/e/df/sadasd/asdasda}{\dotuline{http://www.very.very.very,very.very.very.very.very.very.very.long.url.com/\allowbreak{}a/\allowbreak{}b/\allowbreak{}c/\allowbreak{}d/\allowbreak{}e/\allowbreak{}df/\allowbreak{}sadasd/\allowbreak{}asdasda}}
\end{document}
```

Output:
[image]

Comment: Thanks Richard for your answer, but breakurl is not for pdflatex. Also I cannot store this allowbreak inside the URL entry of Bib(la)tex.

Comment: Hi jos, I'm sorry, but I forgot to remove the breakurl package from the solution (I'll edit the code). This however changes nothing regarding the output. Unfortunately you are right, that das not work with BiB(La)TeX.