# Typography problem for textloss due to perforator – highlight text

Tags: xetex, highlighting

I'm not sure whether help can be found here, but maybe anyone has an idea? I edit letters with XeTeX and many originals of the letters have holes punched with a perforator. It is usually easy to reconstruct the right reading but I need a simple and inoffensive way to mark the text. I can't do grey letters, because I use that for uncertain readings. I don't want to do brackets as that would be too visi[b]le. I can't do underline as I already have that in the text. I thought of making a grey line like a strikethrough only behind not in front of the letters. To achieve that I played around with a framebox with little extension but that seems to be in front of the letters as well. 
Does something come to mind?

Comment: Have a look at Stylistic Set 7 on p. 17 of  `…/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/doc/fonts/junicode/Junicode.pdf`.  Your text has been (accidentally) “deleted” by the perforator, so perhaps a convention for deleted text is not inappropriate.

Comment: @Thérèse Great idea! But two problems arise: 1) What if underline and dots underneath come together? (One could say that dots overrule the underlining.) 2) The real problem to me seems that the holes usually delete one or two characters, too short, to make the dots visible I'd say on the first guess. But I'll try it right away.

Comment: @Thérèse I have a font given to me by the publisher. Dotting with uline isn't working because for an "I" there is just a simple dot underneath, not even placed properly. I found several fragments of code hinting at a proper solution with tikz but my first attempts were not successful as there is a small space added before and after the dotted character when using this code: \newcommand{\udensdot}[1]{%
    \tikz[baseline=(todotted.base)]{
        \node[inner sep=1pt,outer sep=0pt] (todotted) {#1};
        \draw[densely dotted] (todotted.south west)--(todotted.south east);
    }%
}%

Comment: I have little experience with `tikz`.  A gray, dotted underline would be nice, but I’m not sure how to get it.  Have you seen https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/244732?  I suggest gray so that it’s clear that these are obscured characters, not velarized letters.

Comment: I do feel overwhelmed by the TikZ-manual. But i will dig into it. To get the dots gray should be achievable, it seems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I decided to go with a gray underlining. The tikz-solution works because it is possible to combine a bolder gray line with a thin black underline, so I actually can combine both. Another advantage is, that the tikz-underlining allows line break within strike out and underlining. I basically could use the code posted by Peter Grill here:

[Mixing underline and strike-out](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/176118/63249)

The only disadvantage is that tikz needs several runs.