# Inconsistent ulem (with textbf and textit)

Tags: ulem

Using the latest (2012-05-18) [ulem](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/ulem) package gives inconsistent underlining after font changes respectively depending on the position of the underlined text:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{ulem}

\begin{document}
  \textbf{foo} \dashuline{bar}\par
  \textit{foo} \dashuline{bar}\par
  f \dashuline{bar}\par
  fo \dashuline{bar}\par
  foo \dashuline{bar}\par
  foof \dashuline{bar}\par
  foofo \dashuline{bar}\par
\end{document}
```

leads to

[image]

with different a) counts of dashes and b) horizontal placement relative to the underlined word.
Is there a way to get consistent (`\dashuline{bar}` looking exactly the same in all above positions) underlining?

Comment: It seems that `\dashuline` uses a fixed grid.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Package `ulem` uses `\leaders` for the repeated underline elements. For example, `\leaders` is used in the table of contents for the dotted lines. Then the dots are vertically aligned on the page.

The package file `ulem.sty` says in a comment:

> % That concludes the basic underlining.  To put various other objects
>     % (characters) under (or over) text we need to define `\markoverwith`
>     % to set the overlay material in a box, and use leaders of that box for
>     % overlaying the text.  Here, the meaning of `\UL@pixel` is changed so
>     % that  `pixel' size = box size.  Note that we generally need `\leaders`
>     % (not `\cleaders`) for text, because an underline will be a patchwork
>     % of small `\leaders`, and the characters must stay in registration.
>     % However, we "hook" the leaders command so specific applications can
>     % reassign it (`\let\ULleaders\xleaders` or `\let\ULleaders\cleaders`).

Comparison of the three variants:

1. `\leaders`: box units are vertically aligned on the page.
2. `\cleaders`: the box units are centered, remaining space is put at the left and right side of the space to be filled.
3. `\xleaders`: The box units are stretched to fill the space. That means, the distance between the lines can vary.

Test file:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{ulem}

%\let\ULleaders=\leaders % default
%\let\ULleaders=\cleaders
%\let\ULleaders=\xleaders

\begin{document}
  \texttt{\meaning\ULleaders}\par
  \textbf{foo} \dashuline{bar}\par
  \textit{foo} \dashuline{bar}\par
  f \dashuline{bar}\par
  fo \dashuline{bar}\par
  foo \dashuline{bar}\par
  foof \dashuline{bar}\par
  foofo \dashuline{bar}\par
  foofo \dashuline{bari}\par
\end{document}
```

> [image: <code>\leaders</code>]     [image: <code>\cleaders</code>]     [image: <code>\xleaders</code>]

Answer (score 3):

Using TikZ (see [How do I write \underline text but with a dotted line](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/27260/38482)) solves the problem and also allows for fancy customizations (but prohibits linebreaks within an underlined word):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathmorphing} % only for squigglies

\newcommand{\dashuline}[1]{%
  \tikz[baseline=(todotted.base)]{
    \node[inner sep=1pt,outer sep=0pt,draw=none] (todotted) {#1};
    \draw[densely dashed] (todotted.south west) -- (todotted.south east);
  }%
}%

\newcommand{\squigglies}[1]{%
  \tikz[baseline=(squiggled.base)]{
    \node[inner sep=1.25pt,outer sep=0pt,draw=none] (squiggled) {#1};
    \draw[decorate,decoration={snake,amplitude=0.75pt,segment length=1ex}] (squiggled.south west) -- (squiggled.south east);
  }%
}%

\begin{document}
  \textbf{foo} \dashuline{bar} \squigglies{baz}\par
  \textit{foo} \dashuline{bar} \squigglies{baz}\par
  f \dashuline{bar} \squigglies{baz}\par
  fo \dashuline{bar} \squigglies{baz}\par
  foo \dashuline{bar} \squigglies{baz}\par
  foof \dashuline{bar} \squigglies{baz}\par
  foofo \dashuline{bar} \squigglies{baz}\par
\end{document}
```

[image: typeset output of accompanying example]

Comment: Perhaps you could add a small example to show this working in the context of this question.  Otherwise what you have written so far is more a comment than an answer.

Comment: Does the latest edit qualify?

Comment: Yen indeed, it is now much more useful to future visitors.

Answer (score 0):

And the *reason* that `\leaders` are used for `\dashuline` and `\uwave` is that each word and each space is underlined separately, and only `\leaders` keeps the parts synchronized, to ensure all the dashes are equally spaced and all the squiggles join properly.

One could make a variant version that uses only one segment, prohibiting line breaks and flexible spacing, that would work well with `\cleaders` and short arguments (where no line breaking is expected).

Try...

```
\let\origDUL\dashuline
\protected\def\dashuline#1{\leavevmode\begingroup
  \settowidth{\dimen0}{#1}\ifdim\dimen0>3em 
  \origDUL{#1}\else
  \let\ULleaders\cleaders\origDUL{\mbox{#1}}\fi
  \endgroup}
```

Test...

```
\let\ULleaders=\leaders % default
\texttt{\meaning\ULleaders}\par
f \dashuline{bar} and \dashuline{The box units are stretched to fill the space.}\par
fo \dashuline{bar} and \dashuline{The box units are stretched to fill the space.}\par
foo \dashuline{bar} and \dashuline{The box units are stretched to fill the space.}\par
foof \dashuline{bar} and \dashuline{The box units are stretched to fill the space.}\par
foofo \dashuline{bar} and \dashuline{The box units are stretched to fill the space.}\par
foofo \dashuline{bar} and \dashuline{The box units are stretched to fill the space.}\par
```