# How to underline enumerate label with dotted line?

Tags: tikz-pgf, enumitem, ulem

The `ulem` package provides several commands for underlining text. I tried all of these commands to style the label in my `enumerate` environment. Some of the commands work, some of them do not. I'm afraid these ones I want to use for my document doesn't work.

- what works: `\uline{}`, `\uuline{}`, `\uwave{}`, `\sout{}`, `\xout{}`
- what doesn't work: `\dashuline{}`, `\dotuline{}`

The following code works

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{ulem} 

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}[label = \uline{\textit{Step \arabic*:}}]
\item First item.
\item Second item
\item A third item
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

The following code doesn't work

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{ulem} 

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}[label = \dashuline{\textit{Step \arabic*:}}]
\item First item.
\item Second item
\item A third item
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

**Additional information**
Thanks to Christan's answer even underlining with `TikZ` is no problem anymore. In my case I'll use TikZ (instead of the `ulem` package) which allows to easily modify the style of underlining (like mentioned in this post: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/27260/101831).

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{ulem}

\usepackage{tikz}

\newcommand{\udot}[1]{
    \tikz[baseline=(todotted.base)]{
        \node[inner sep=1pt,outer sep=0pt] (todotted) {#1};
        \draw[dotted] (todotted.south west) -- (todotted.south east);
    }
}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}[label =\protect\udot{\textit{Step \arabic*:}}]
\item First item.
\item Second item
\item A third item
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Please have a look at http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/4736/what-is-the-difference-between-fragile-and-robust-commands

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to to `\protect` `\dashuline`,that's all. However, I doubt this style of typography ;-) (The some is true for `\dotuline`).

Contrary to `\uline` etc. `\dashuline` is no robust command, i.e. it's fragile.

Other way: Use `\robustify{\dashuline}` (needs `etoolbox` package), `\protect` is not needed then.

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{ulem} 

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}[label = \uline{\textit{Step \arabic*:}}]
\item First item.
\item Second item
\item A third item
\end{enumerate}

\begin{enumerate}[label = \protect\dashuline{\textit{Step \arabic*:}}]
\item First item.
\item Second item
\item A third item
\end{enumerate}
\begin{enumerate}[label=\protect\dotuline{\textit{Step \arabic*:}}]
\item First item.
\item Second item
\item A third item
\end{enumerate}


\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Is there a reason why `\dashuline` needs `\protect` and `\uline{}` not?

Comment: @Sr.Schneider: I've edited some seconds ago  ;-)

Comment: You could clarify (or even add an small example) that `\robustify` is intended to the preamble, so you don't have to alter the code of the document.

Comment: @Manuel: I could, but if compare some other solutions here on this platforms I have the impression that I provide sometimes too much and one-line-solutions by others gets the tick/upvotes ;-) and a lot of complains about do this or do that with mine

Comment: Mmm... I don't follow. I'm just suggesting that you add a little bit of explanation, i.e., to expand one of your lines.

Comment: @Manuel: I hinted that I a provide a lot of explanations, detailed examples in my answers and others provide a single line of code (to the same question), get a bunch of votes and my answer is basically disregarded)

Comment: Mmm... still don't see the relation. In fact I do agree with what you are saying, yes, it's true that *single lines get a bunch of votes and long detailed answers are basically disregarded*. You can add a few explanation or don't add it, but I don't see what are you trying to say

Comment: @Manuel: It's about the effort and the resulting appreciation