# How to adjust dotted line in tikz example

Tags: tikz-styles

I saw [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/27258/how-do-i-write-underline-text-but-with-a-dotted-line) to add a dotted line below some text. But I'm wondering how to shift it down a little bit and play with its positioning, I don't see how to adjust the layout of it from the example.

I would also like to know how to simply add a "blank line", basically like this in the text:

```
Hello this is some text with a ___________ blank line.
```

I tried doing this but it doesn't seem right and doesn't work:

```
Hello this is some text with a \thedot{          } blank line.

\newcommand{\thedot}[1]{%
  \tikz[baseline=(todotted.base)]{
    \node[inner sep=1pt,outer sep=0pt] (todotted) {#1};
    \draw[dotted, thick] (todotted.south west) -- (todotted.south east);
  }%
}%
```

I get this with the current answers:

[image]

When I do `\node[inner sep=1pt,outer sep=0pt,xshift=-2mm]` or `\tikz[baseline=2mm]`. Still not right.

Comment: Did you try using `\phantom{some text}` to get some blank space?

Comment: As @nidhin says, replace `thedot{     }` with `\thedot{\hphantom{some text}}`, where `some text` represents the amount of space you want. Multiple spaces are ignored in text, so what you have is the equivalent of `\thedot{ }` (ie, a single space). The other alternative is to modify `thedot` macro to have a parameter which specifies the actual width of the dotted line you want to have: `\thedot[2cm]{}` for example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With tikz, just use the `baseline` key, see page 124 of manual 3.0.1a. 
I colored the lines to make the code easier to read.

#### To respond to your last comment:

baseline is defined on page 124 as follows:

```
/tikz/baseline=< dimension or coordinate or default >
```

Thus, natively we can do with either a coordinate or a dimension, but not both at the same time.
To apply both at the same time, a `transform canvas={yshift=-2pt}` can be applied in this way:

```
\tikz[baseline=(todotted.base)]\path[red, dash dot dot,transform canvas={yshift=-2pt}] node  (todotted) {} edge ([xshift=2cm]todotted){};
```

Code and result:

```
  \documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
Hello this is some text with a \tikz[baseline]\draw[dashed](0,0)--+(1,0); blank line.

Hello this is some text with a \tikz[baseline=-2mm]\draw[red,thick,densely dotted](0,0)--+(1,0); blank line.

Hello this is some text with a \tikz[baseline=1mm]\draw[blue,thick,dotted](0,0)--+(1,0); blank line.

Hello this is some text with a \tikz[baseline=(todotted.base)]\path[cyan, loosely dash dot ] node  (todotted) {} edge ([xshift=2cm]todotted){}; blank line.

Hello this is some text with a \tikz[baseline=(todotted.base)]\path[red, dash dot dot,transform canvas={yshift=-2pt}] node  (todotted) {} edge ([xshift=2cm]todotted){}; blank line.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: It has `\tikz[baseline=(todotted.base)]`, I'm not sure how to do essentially this: `\tikz[baseline=(todotted.base) - 2pt]`.

Comment: I just updated my answer

Comment: still don't how to do an offset like in `\tikz[baseline=(todotted.base) - 2pt]`

Comment: I just updated my answer

Answer (score 2):

**Solid line:** The command is `\rule[lift]{width}{thickness}`.

```
Hello this is some text with a \rule[0pt]{1cm}{.4pt} blank line.

Hello this is some text with a \rule[2pt]{1cm}{.4pt} blank line.

Hello this is some text with a \rule[-2pt]{1cm}{.4pt} blank line.
```

[image]

**Dotted line:** Using a box, we define a new command with width as argument.

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{report}

\newcommand{\dottedline}[1]{\makebox[#1]{\dotfill}}
\begin{document}
Hello this is some text with a \dottedline{2cm}  blank line.

Hello this is some text with a \dottedline{3cm}  blank line.
\end{document}
```

[image: ![enter image description here]

**Edit:**

[image]

You can change the `5mm` value (distance between dots) and `{\Large .}` (the symbol to be used to fill.

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{report}

\makeatletter
\def\mydotsfill{\leavevmode \cleaders \hb@xt@ 5mm{\hss {\Large .}\hss }\hfill \kern \z@}
\newcommand{\dottedline}[1]{\makebox[#1]{\mydotsfill}}
\makeatother


\begin{document}
Hello this is some text with a \dottedline{2cm}  blank line.

Hello this is some text with a \dottedline{3cm}  blank line.

\end{document}
```

**Edit 2:** Another version, where you can give an optional argument with the text to be inserted above the dots, centered.

[image]

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\makeatletter
\def\mydotsfill{\leavevmode \cleaders \hb@xt@ 3mm{\hss {\Large .}\hss }\hfill \kern \z@}
\newcommand{\dottedline}[2][]{\makebox[#2]{\mydotsfill\makebox[0pt]{\raisebox{.75ex}{#1}}\mydotsfill}}
\makeatother


\begin{document}
Hello this is some text with a \dottedline[December]{5cm}  blank line.

Hello this is some text with a \dottedline{3cm}  blank line.

\end{document}
```

Comment: I would like a dotted line if possible :)

Comment: I would like to control the spacing between the dots (make them a little tighter too) if possible :D

Comment: getting `! Undefined control sequence.
\mydotsfill ->\leavevmode \cleaders \hb`

Comment: I also want to be able to have text over the line in some cases.

Comment: @LancePollard, see edit 2.