# Underline text with === (SETEX style)

Tags: r, typewriter, underline, emphasis

I'm trying to recreate the typewriter look.

How to make `\underline{sometext}` work like SETEX-style section marker?

The intended use is with monospaced/typewriter fonts for lines with plenty of space beneath them (like section headings).

Illustration of desired effect below.

[image: Underline text SETEX style]

Comment: Related/possible starting point: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/27258/how-do-i-write-underline-text-but-with-a-dotted-line and https://superuser.com/questions/1136672/double-underline-one-of-them-dashed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For example using `\halign` and `\leaders` primitives:

```
\def\underlined#1{\vtop{\tt\halign{##\cr#1\cr\leaders\hbox{=}\hfill\cr}}}

Text: \underlined{Odwolanie upowaznienia}

\bye
```

Comment: Neat solution with `\leaders`

Comment: How do you adjust the distance of the underlining from the underlined text?

Comment: @MarekKowalczyk Using `\noalign{\kern-1pt}` (-1pt just for example) inserted between second `\cr` and `\leaders` in the macro.

Comment: This works: `\def\underlined#1{\vtop{\halign{##\cr#1\cr\noalign{\kern-6pt}\leaders\hbox{=}\hfill\cr}}}`

Answer (score 1):

The real typewriter look can be achieved by setting a number of `=` below the title. Here is an example with `\section`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xstring}
\usepackage{multido}
\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}
\usepackage[default]{sourcecodepro}

\newcommand\setex[1]
  {#1 \\ \StrLen{#1}[\len]\multido{}{\len}{=}}

\titleformat{\section}
  {\normalfont\filcenter}{}{0pt}{\setex{#1}}

\begin{document}

\section{Test}

Lorem ipsum...

\end{document}
```

[image]

This will not work for really long section titles.

Comment: How do you adjust the distance of the underlining from the underlined text?

Comment: It's just a simple line of text, you can try adjusting the baseline or something like that

Comment: This works: `\newcommand\setex[1]{#1 \\ \StrLen{#1}[\len]\kern-4pt\multido{}{\len}{=}}`