# How to "cut" terms of a expression?

Tags: math-mode

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to strike through obliquely, e.g. to indicate cancellation?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/40253/how-to-strike-through-obliquely-e-g-to-indicate-cancellation)

Like in the image below (see `2x` and `-2x`):

[image]

Comment: See eg the `cancel` package.

Comment: @cyberSingularity - thank you. But i didnt find how to increase the tickness of the line.

Comment: `\usepackage[thicklines]{cancel}`

Comment: There are also other solutions, see eg http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/15958/17427. You can change `\draw[red]` there to `\draw[red,thick]` in the first example etc to suit your tastes, or `draw=red` to `draw=red,thick` in the second example in that answer (which has the benefit of being a compilable example).